# Notation of transformation of random variables/repeated trials

Tags: statistics

Say I had $X\sim N\left ( \mu ,\sigma ^ 2 \right )$

How would I notate, say, $X_1 + X_2 + X_3$, vs $3 \cdot X_1$. It's caused me a lot of stupid confusion as obviously the two variances will be different, and I've been writing both as 3X

Comment: Exactly as you wrote. If $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are random variables, of any kind, their sum is written $X_1+X_2+X_3$. Remember that different random variables can have the same distribution. If we toss two dice, a red and a blue, the number on the red has the same distribution as the number on the blue. But these are different random variables.